# How to trigger v-on:change after input has finished updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to figure out how to update an input field after a user has finished typing their changes. What I am noticing is that the event that I call when doing @change occurs when I click off of the input box, which is not what I want. I want it to wait until i am done making inputs, then make a change.

For Reference.

The form:

```
<b-form  @submit.stop.prevent>
     <b-input
          v-model="round_Title"
          placeholder="Round Title"
          :state="null"
          id="feedbacek-user"
          size="sm"
          @change="updateTitle()"
          v-if="validation">
       </b-input>
</b-form>
```

updateTitle():

```
updateTitle() {
            console.log('made it');
        },
```

Comment: What do you mean by "done making inputs"?

Comment: try @input it might be what you want

Comment: @Robodude I want it to fire off the function once i am done typing